# Change the system version of nodejs - ubuntu

Tags: node.js, shell, ubuntu

I just started to use node.js in local projects few days ago. My application works good, if I run it from command shell

```
nvm run 0.10.32 ./bin/www app
```

or

```
node ./bin/www app
```

So, it works with node version 0.10.xx or higher. But there is a problem: I can't debug it from WebStorm - it throws lots of errors. I went to settings and was stunned: "Node.js core modules version is 0.6.12". Then, I've checked the installed versions of node and it returns

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/$ nvm ls
```

->  v0.10.24
    v0.10.32
      system

and when I type

```
nvm use system
```

it says,

```
/home/user/.nvm/*/bin removed from $PATH
/home/user/.nvm/*/share/man removed from $MANPATH
/home/user/.nvm/*/lib/node_modules removed from $NODE_PATH
Now using system version of node: v0.6.12.
```

Obviously, I need to change the system version of nodejs. I tried to update, remove, reinstall - no results, it still has this version. 
All I need is being able to debug my application code from webstorm. How can I get it - change system version of node, or maybe another ways?
Any tips would be very helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Verify that default node is really coming from nvm with `which node`, if its not, you can safely run :

```
rm `which node`
```

To set the default node version with nvm use :

```
nvm alias default 0.10.32
```

If you have many apps that use different node version, add a .npmrc in the root directory in each of them. .npmrc only contains the version, e.g. "v0.10.32".

Then each time you `cd` into a project run

```
nvm use
```

Answer (score 1):

You must install the version you need:

```
nvm install x.y.z
```

and then define the **alias** for that version:

```
nvm alias default x.y.z
```

**Note:** you must restart (close and reopen) your terminal in order to have the changes applied.

Answer (score 0):

a not quite sustainable solution is simply create symbolic links:

```
sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node"
sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/npm" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
```